# How would I adapt this browser code to run on my Node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies

```
var templateSource = document.getElementById('result-template').innerHTML,
  template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource),
  resultsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('result'),
  loginButton = document.getElementById('btn-login');
```

Now I do not understand what this code is exactly is exactly doing. I got this code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/62wafrm7/) and have placed it into my `srcServer.js`. I have included the `document` lib through the line `import document from 'document';`, but am getting the error below:

```
/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS 4/buildScripts/srcServer.js:71
  var templateSource = _document2.default.getElementById('result-template').innerHTML,
                                          ^

TypeError: _document2.default.getElementById is not a function
    at /Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS 4/buildScripts/srcServer.js:60:35
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS 4/buildScripts/srcServer.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at loader (/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS 4/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS 4/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at /Users/sharanduggirala/Documents/UID/CS235ProjectJS 4/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:159:24
```

for the line below:

```
var templateSource = document.getElementById('result-template').innerHTML
```

I have included document in the dependencies inside `package.json` too:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "document": "0.4.7",
...
```

Am I supposed to get more files from the example online? I am not sure as to what the error here is. There are some files in the `JFiddle` example:

[image]

Am I supposed to include them in my project, and if so, in the `src` folder?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I don't understand that myself.

Comment: That code is browser code and needs content in a DOM in order to do anything useful.  It gets some text from the page which is apparently formatted as a handlebars template, then compiles that template (turning it into HTML), then finds two other elements in the page.  It doesn't actually do anything with the HTML.  This code is entirely designed to run in a browser.  Why are you trying to run it in node.js?  What are YOU trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have slightly modified the question to reflect some of my understanding of the problem.

Comment: The document dependency that you have specified is a node.js package for generating documentation. It is not in anyway related to the global "document" variable. Perhaps there is a conflict between the document module you are importing and the global variable which is causing this issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 As you can see from the `JFiddle` example, I am trying to access the Spotify API, login and get info.

Comment: @Sridhar that would make an incredible amount of sense!

Comment: Are you running this in node.js or in the browser?  If you're running it in the browser, then remove the node.js tag.  If you have a jsFiddle for your code, show the link to the actual jsFiddle, not a screenshot.  This question is completely unclear for what you're trying to accomplish and what environment you are running it in.  You don't run browser code in node.js.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've grabbed some browser code and am trying to make it run on my VScode environment using `node.js`

Comment: Why?  That's rarely the right way to do things in node.js.  Write node.js code to run in node.js.  Right now, this question seems like a waste of time.  You need to specify the actual problem to be solved and then we can help you with the right way to solve that in node.js.  Not try to fix a flawed approach with no idea what you're trying to accomplish.  Waste of our time right now.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have actually given the link of the `JFiddle` site where I grabbed the code from.

Comment: I think you need to `require('document')`

Comment: This code is meant to run in a browser, not in node.js.  Write node.js code to run in node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var templateSource = document.getElementById('result-template').innerHTML,
template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource),
resultsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('result'),
loginButton = document.getElementById('btn-login');
```

There is a couple things going on here. One is some short-hand variable declaration, so let's change that so it's more clear:

```
var templateSource = document.getElementById('result-template').innerHTML;

var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

var resultsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('result');

var loginButton = document.getElementById('btn-login');
```

Here's what I see happening without having any understanding of Handlebars besides it being a templating engine:

```
// find an element on your page that has id="result-template"
// look for something like <div id="result-template">
// .innerHTML takes the content from that element and preserves the HTML part of it
// there is also .innerText which would strip the HTML out
var templateSource = document.getElementById('result-template').innerHTML;

// run that content from above through a compile function
// this is probably used to help Handlebars understand the HTML
// and so Handlebars can re-render it
var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

// this is simply getting an element called id="result" (ie: <div id="result">)
// once your code has this element, it can execute further logic on it
// try typing it into your console: document.getElementById('result')
// see what is displayed
// this also doesn't appear connected with the first two lines of code
var resultsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('result');

// this is also not connected to the other three lines of code.
// it is also finding an element by ID
// clearly a login button, for some reason
var loginButton = document.getElementById('btn-login');
```

Hopefully that is helpful.

It looks like your problem is that `document` is not defined, or it isn't **the** document.